# WordPress Contact Form 7 – How to handle more than one file attachment?

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm currently try to make job application form where you the user able to upload their resume, and cover letter. I already align the file attachment according to the documentation like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1njs.png)

However, only the Cover Letter file I have received... Which I figured the file could be only receive the latest upload file. Since the cover letter is after the resume:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WN2Jo.png)

I tried again delete the [file-cover-letter] but still able the cover letter upload, and then when I receive the form. only the cover letter received, so I was right it was only receive the latest upload file.

How to obtain all the file attachment for each upload file input?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) (you will also get better feedback with your question.) And welcome to Stack Overflow (SO) @Edberaga

Comment: Kindly, you should ask that in "Contact Form 7" plugin support pages and wait for an answer, as your problem is related to form settings in a plugin, and not about a real code attempt where you have some issue.

Comment: Alright, I will ask this to the plugin support.

Comment: Your mail attachments configuration is correct as per [CF7 documentation](https://contactform7.com/file-uploading-and-attachment/) so either you have an error on your server (enable `W_DEBUG` to check) or there is a bug in the plugin itself.